# Arabic data is showing ????? characters from asp.net mvc to ios app using afnetworking library

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, arabic

Arabic data is showing ????? characters from asp.net mvc to ios app using afnetworking library to handle the response object.

```
#import "AppGateway.h"

//the web location of the service
#define kAPIHost @"domain"
#define kAPIPath @"Home/GetNews/"

@implementation AppGateway

/*Singleton*/
+(AppGateway*)sharedInstance
{
    static AppGateway *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAPIHost]];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
-(AppGateway*)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self!=nil) {
        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)commandWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params onCompletion:(JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock{
    NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest = [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                      path:kAPIPath
                                                                parameters:params
                                                 constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData){
    }];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:apiRequest];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
        NSLog(@"AFNTSUCCESS");
        //This is where response object carry arabic data corrupted to '??????????'
        completionBlock(responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"AFNTFAILURE");
        completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"error"]);
    }];
    [operation start];
}

@end
```

This is my class i'm using in order to connect to the mvc actions.
Thank you

Comment: there might be problem with webservice response encoding, if its not there then you have to encode data and display it, if you get correct data from service you can display it in arabic with [this useful class](https://github.com/Accorpa/Arabic-Converter-From-and-To-Arabic-Presentation-Forms-B)

Comment: thank you for your help it worked as i mentioned below, and it was a problem on the server database.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly was the problem because i'm facing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it worked it is not from the afnetworking or mvc the problem was with in the server. sorry for that

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: It is just that the problem appeared to be from somewhere completely irrelevant to the question topic, the problem was while saving the arabic data in database and has nothing related to AFnetworking

Comment: ok what was the problem in the server?

Comment: It is definitely good to know that the problem was with the server to save people from needlessly messing with AFNetworking encoding. But yes, it would be great to know what the problem with the server was.

Comment: what was the problem?