# getting "???" value from arabic characters in swift3

Tags: ios, mysql, json, swift3

Im getting ???? values from arabic characters in MySQL database. With swift 3, I'm using JSON to get the array data, then if I print the result in English it's fine but with arabic it's showing "??? ???? "

Two questions:
1) Do you think the problem is response from JSON?

2) If JSON response is the problem, I'm confused with how to execute the conversion. Anyone can demonstrate the codings?

Here's my Code

```
Alamofire.request(URL_USER_LOGIN, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
{
    response in
    //printing response
    print(response)

    //getting the json value from the server
    if let result = response.result.value {
        let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary

        //if there is no error
        if(!(jsonData.value(forKey: "error") as! Bool)){

            //getting the user from response
            let user = jsonData.value(forKey: "username") as! NSDictionary
            print (user)

            //getting user values
            let userFname = user.value(forKey: "customers_firstname") as! String

            //saving user values to defaults
            self.defaultValues.set(userFname, forKey: "customers_firstname")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arabic data is showing ????? characters from asp.net mvc to ios app using afnetworking library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162494/arabic-data-is-showing-characters-from-asp-net-mvc-to-ios-app-using-afnetw)

Comment: @JonSnow how's Sansa? lol nope this is diff

Comment: Who is sansa ? here